# Create Imagebutton Dynamically C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout, imagebutton

I have done the classic Tic Tac Toe game in C# (xamarin) for Android, and now I have to add a new "modality" that taking into account the choose of the player, the app have to create a grid nxn (for example if the player input is "5", I have to create a grid 5x5). In the other "modality" of the app, I have handle the grid with LinearLayout and an array of Imagebutton (for the classic mode, I have 3 LinearLayout each with 3 imagebutton). Now how can I create a grid of n and handle the touch? I have tried with a "for" but obviously the imagebutton are all in the same row...I don't know how to change row

[image: Empty layout]
[image: Populated]

```
LinearLayout row1 = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
int n = 4;

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{    
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
    button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);          
    row1.AddView(button);

}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="6"
android:background="#c7efb1">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="385.0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50.0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:background="#fff4f4f4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Team O"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/teamO" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Team X"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/teamX" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:background="#fff4f4f4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/punteggioO" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="15.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/punteggioX" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55.0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="#fff4f4f4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
    <Button
        android:text="Restart"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/restart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assign a `Tag` to each of the buttons which tell you which Row/Column they belong to, then assign all of the button's `Click` `event` to the same event, where you then fish out that `Tag` to see which one was clicked.

In your case, I would probably also generate the Layouts for the rows dynamically, since you can have N rows and N columns.

In the following code the Green area in your screen shot would be the `root`.

**Create Button Method**

First I define a `CreateButton` method, which creates each button from a `row`, `column`, modify this to your liking so they look as you want:

```
Button CreateButton(int row, int column)
{
    var text = $"{row},{column}";
    var button = new Button(this)
    {
        Tag = new Java.Lang.String(text),
        Text = text,
        LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
        { Weight = 1 }
    };
    button.Click += ButtonClicked;

    return button;
}
```

Important to note here is that, since I am using a `LinearLayout` for the row layout, and I want the buttons to be equal size, I use `Weight` equal to 1. That is also why `Width` is set to 0 in the layout parameters.

The other important thing here is that I assign the `Tag`. Since it expects a `Java.Lang.Object` I wrap using `Java.Lang.String`.

**Create Row Method**

```
LinearLayout CreateRowLayout()
{
    var row = new LinearLayout(this)
    {
        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
        LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        { Weight = 1 }
    };
    return row;
}
```

Very simple `LinearLayout`, again with `Weight` set to 1, to make all rows equal height.

**Create Rows and Columns Method**

Now lets populate the view by creating `n` rows and `n` columns.

```
IEnumerable<LinearLayout> CreateLayouts(int n)
{
    var rows = new List<LinearLayout>();

    for (var row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        var rowLayout = CreateRowLayout();
        for (var column = 0; column < n; column++)
            rowLayout.AddView(CreateButton(row, column));
        rows.Add(rowLayout);
    }

    return rows;
}
```

This is pretty simple, for each row, create `n` buttons. Return as list.

**Add to our rows/columns to the View**

Now as I noted above, `root` in this case could come from your `AXML` file. adjust so it fits your code.

```
var root = new LinearLayout(this)
{
    LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent),
    Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
};

var children = CreateLayouts(4);
foreach (var child in children)
    root.AddView(child);
```

The only important thing here is that the orientation of the `LinearLayout` for `root` is set to `Vertical` so the rows flow downwards.

**Reacting to button click**

Now lets fish out the Button click! There is a bit of casting happening here because I converted the row/column into a `Java.Lang.String` to assign it to the `Tag`. Not much voodoo about it though, just grunt work.

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;

    var tag = button.Tag.JavaCast<Java.Lang.String>();
    var tagString = tag.ToString();
    var tagParts = tagString.Split(',');
    var row = tagParts[0];
    var column = tagParts[1];

    Toast.MakeText(this, $"{row},{column}", ToastLength.Short).Show();

    // do something based on row/column
}
```

This is it! We now have a layout that should look like this:

[image: Our view]

Pressing each button will show a Toast, but adjust to your liking.

**EDIT**

Change the `LinearLayout` for your mainLayout to:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="385.0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" />
```

Then in your `OnCreate` or method in your `Activity` or `OnCreateView` in your `Fragment` depending on what you use add:

```
var root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout);
```

Then simply add the code to generate the buttons right after:

```
var children = CreateLayouts(4);
foreach (var child in children)
    root.AddView(child);
```

Comment: thank you fo your answer, now i have a problem with "root", my "green area" linear layout, have id = "mainLayout" , how can i redirect root to mainLayout? i have tried with var root=FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout) but does not work

Comment: Add your layout to your question and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Added more to the answer

Comment: don't let me to use the method "AddView" on "root" ("view" do not contain a definition of "addView")

Comment: Use the Generic version of FindViewById, I've edited my answer.

Comment: thank you! now the procedure work, but i have another 2 question to you, why the last rows are not high then the other (https://ibb.co/kfKXiv)? and can i use ImageButton instead of Button? or can i apply image to a button?

Comment: Adjust your Layout Weights and WeightSums so they aren't squeezed. You could probably just remove: `android:weightSum="3"` in the mainLayout